# 3DS2 on iOS and Android: HPP or API?

Tags: realex-payments-api

I was browsing through the documentation and was wondering about what is the recommendation for intergation for 3DS2 payments on android and iOS devices. My application would be available in web and mobile, so I thought having my server just using API SDK would be sufficient.

Would this approach be correct or should I opt to use HPP? What are the advantages/disadvantages to chosing API or HPP?

Thanks in advance.